# How to make model field that can has several values in django

Tags: django, django-models, model

I want to make a blog in Django.
The blog has `Article, Author ...` models.

each article has many resources. it looks like this on the article page:
`Resources: Medium, Hashnode, Dev community, ...`

I want that while adding an article, the admin can dynamically these article resources.

for the author, I want to add social links.
every author's social media are different. one may have `Facebook, LinkedIn ...` and the other may have `Instagram, Twitter, ...`

I want the admin (or author)  can add any social media for the authors.

**Update:**

model implementation of `Article:`

```
class Article(models.Model):
"""Model definition for Article."""

title = models.CharField(
    max_length=100
)

slug = models.SlugField(
    max_length=100, 
    unique=True, 
    db_index=True
)

excerpt = models.TextField(
    max_length=200
)

body = models.TextField(
    max_length=10000,
    validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)]
)

image = models.ImageField(
    upload_to='images/blog',
)

image_resource = models.CharField(
    max_length=100,
    verbose_name="Image Resource Name",
    null=True, 
    blank=True
)

related_articles = models.ManyToManyField(
    'self',
    symmetrical=True,
    related_name='related_articles',
    verbose_name='Related Articles',
    blank=True
)

date_published = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now_add=True
)

author = models.ForeignKey(
    Author,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='Articles',
)

category = models.ForeignKey(
    'Category',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='Articles',
    blank=True,
    null=True
)

tags = models.ManyToManyField(
    'Tag',
    verbose_name='Tags'
)
```

model implementation of `Author:`

```
class Author(models.Model):
"""Model definition for Author."""

first_name = models.CharField(
    max_length=50
)

last_name = models.CharField(
    max_length=50
)

profile_pic = models.ImageField(
    upload_to='profile_pics', 
    default='images/boy.jpg'
)

email = models.EmailField(
    max_length=254
)

bio = models.TextField(
    max_length=1000
)

facebook = models.URLField(
    max_length=254,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    verbose_name='Facebook URL'
)
 
instagram = models.URLField(
    max_length=254,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    verbose_name='Instagram URL'
)

twitter = models.URLField(
    max_length=254,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    verbose_name='Twitter URL'
)

linkedin = models.URLField(
    max_length=254,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    verbose_name='LinkedIn URL'
)
```

Comment: can you show us your model code attempt?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the question and provided model implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Look for an existing Django package that might handle what you want to have happen.

Aside from that, I can't think of a way that you can dynamically add these into a particular model.  You'd have to include all of the different types of social media you feel an individual could possibly have ahead of of time.

You might be able to "fake it" by setting up a Profile for your authors that enables them to add a key:value pair into a field in the model as they desire to add social media accounts but that's about all I can suggest at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, @RiverRook, yeah that's also a solution. I might implement your solution if couldn't find a better solution.